How to characterize a dataset
I know we can compute a correlation matrix for continuous variables in a dataset. However, to summarize the degree of correlations between variables, is it possible to do a mean or something else based on the correlation matrix?
In addition, apart from numbers of variables, sample size, what else can characterize a dataset (better a single number) from statistical or ML point of view?

Would you mean something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summary_statistics?  Could you clarify what you mean by "summarize the degree of correlations" and what your purpose is?

Yes, something like what is described in the wiki. What I mean is whether there is a way to summarize the correlation matrix into a single number so that this number kind of reflects how correlated variables are in the dataset, as the matrix reports the pairwise correlation.

The issue is that the correlation matrix is a complicated beast when more than two variables are involved: no one number adequately summarizes it in general. For examples, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110416, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284861, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637089,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59446 (about graphical summaries), https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23353 (PCA et al.), etc.

Possibly useful on Math.SE: What does Determinant of Covariance Matrix give?
